# Stuck on Installing PHP plugin PDT on eclipse luna

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-luna

I'm facing a boring situation i am unable to install PDT on my eclipse luna using Downloaded zip of PDT v3.4 or the url link with the eclipse's tool Install new Software lead to the same situation even with even with version 3.3.
[image]
[image]
I'm using eclipse luna x64bit, jdk8 x64 on window 8.1 x64

here is the original error

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) JUnit Tests 3.3.0.201406110111 (org.eclipse.php.test.feature.group 3.3.0.201406110111)
  Missing requirement: PDT Core Unit Tests 3.3.0.201406110111 (org.eclipse.php.core.tests 3.3.0.201406110111) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PHP Development Tools (PDT) JUnit Tests 3.3.0.201406110111 (org.eclipse.php.test.feature.group 3.3.0.201406110111)
    To: org.eclipse.php.core.tests [3.3.0.201406110111]
```

I don't understand what is going on because il installed PDT in a 32bit win7 machine without problem

Comment: use netbeans, much better in my opinion.

Comment: I want to use eclipse. as I Said pdt got installed in an old 32bit machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured out what was the problem. The problem was the ISP Network not good of firewalled . i changed to another ISP and got stuff installed!

Answer (score 0):

Remove PDT Junit and PDT Source code . It's required if you working on PDT extensions.

You need only first feature from list +mylyn integration if you using it.

If you installing PDT from zip or pdt update site you have to select "Contact all update sites during install required software", see http://eclipse.org/pdt.

PDT 3.4 is also available in marketplace.

Comment: Already tried all your suggestion but noting is working always the same error